# Optimize table command

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to run a code that optimizes tables in the database. I want to run this query in loop as each table take 3-5 mins to execute so once the execution of one table is done the other table should execute. Any suggestions regarding it.

```
const test=  'OPTIMIZE TABLE TestT1';
connection.query(test, function (error, results, fields) {
    
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        callback(error, "Error: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log("Query success");
        console.log("results:",results);
        callback(error, results.length > 0 ? results : null);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this code or are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think he's asking how to write a loop that waits for the previous async query to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that optimizes a single table and returns a promise you can wait for. Put all the tables into an array, loop over the array, awaiting the function.

```js
function optimize_table(connection, tablename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    connection.query(`OPTIMIZE TABLE ${tablename}`, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    })
  });
}

const tables = ["table1", "table2"];
for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  await optimize_table(connection, tables[i]));
}
```

For more ideas, see [How to interact with MySQL database using async/await promises in node.js](https://darifnemma.medium.com/how-to-interact-with-mysql-database-using-async-await-promises-in-node-js-9e6c81b683da)

Answer (score 0):

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is essentially useless, especially for `ENGINE=InnoDB`.  I recommend you abandon the process rather than trying to speed it up.

One of the rare cases where `OPTIMIZE` can be useful is just after deleting lots of rows from a table.  But there are better ways to do the delete, so that is another case to simply avoid.